# Why does Postgres tell me "no pg_hba.conf entry for host..." when I have already modified this file?

Tags: linux, networking, postgresql, database-connection

The story so far:

- I have installed **Postgres** on my **Linux** based desktop (HOST).
- I have created a test database, with test data, on HOST.
- I have added to the end of the **pg_hba.conf** file on HOST: `host samerole all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`
- I have added to the end of the **postgresql.conf** file on HOST: `listen_addresses = '*'`
- I have installed **PGAdmin4** on the Linux virtual machine of my Chromebook (CLIENT).
- The IP address of HOST is 192.168.1.159, and the port is 5432.
- If I run `telnet 192.168.1.159 5432` on CLIENT, it seems to connect.
- However, if try to connect to the same IP address and port via the PGAdmin GUI, it responds:

> Unable to connect to server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.208", user "postgis_user", database "postgis_prototype", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.208", user "postgis_user", database "postgis_prototype", SSL off

- If I try to connect via the command line, I get a very similar response.

**Does anyone know why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), the meaning of `samerole` in the **database** column is:

> The value samerole specifies that the requested user must be a member
> of the role with the same name as the requested database.

The error message indicates that the rejected connection is attempted with `user "postgis_user", database "postgis_prototype"`. Since the user name and database name differ, the rule with `samerole` cannot match  (well, unless there is a `postgis_prototype` role with `postgis_user` as a member, but if you had set that up, surely you would have mentioned it in the question).

The simplest solution is probably to list the authorized databases in the 2nd column, the authorized users in the 3rd column, and forget about using `samerole`.

You may use comma-separated list in these columns, or split them into several rules.

The rules in `pg_hba.conf` are evaluated from top to bottom, stopping at the first matching rule.

The solution of accepting everything with `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` is indeed not recommended at all if your server can be reached from the Internet. There are evil bots out there that try to connect as the `postgres` superuser to every reachable Postgres installation.

Comment: Does the `md5` at the end not offer password protection, even in the `all all` case? As things are, when I connect to my database remotely, I still have to supply the password corresponding to the `postgis_user` username. Are you saying that a malicious bot could bypass that password protection if the `all all` setting was used?

Comment: @TomHosker: No, a bot cannot bypass it, but it might use brute force. For example: [pgminer](https://www.securityweek.com/pgminer-crypto-mining-botnet-abuses-postgresql-distribution).

Comment: Forgive me for playing devil's advocate, but could it not also brute force the correct username and database name too?

Comment: @TomHosker: technically yes, but bots want superuser accounts. Anyway the recommendation **not to** use `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` often means in practice to filter on the origin of the connection. For instance, it's very common to use `host all all 192.168.1.0/24 md5` if the local network has addresses in the 192.168.1.* range.

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution: if I change the line added to **pg_hba.conf** to:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Then everything works as expected. But this amendment may cause unacceptable security issues that I haven't anticipated.